# Are there any tools to visualize the objects being used in a program?

Tags: java, visualization

I'm not sure how useful this would be, but I thought it might be neat to visualize the objects being used in my program and which objects are being referenced from where. I'm guessing it would generate some data that would be used by a program like graphviz. Are there any tools that do this, otherwise how hard would it be to do this myself? Ideally this would work for any arbitrary program, though if necessary I could make some modifications to the code (such as to add a dumpObjects() call or whatever)

I'm interested in doing this for java, but if there are solutions for other languages please post those too.

Comment: Yeah, I've long wished for something like this in C#; tried to work on it but it required a profiler. In Java you can generate the relevant information via AOP; C# doesn't have great support for that.

Comment: The question is pretty old but still relevant. Such a tool would be nice to find why some objects are not garbage-collected and resolve memory leaks. Profilers are ok, but the problem is that the stop at 1 level, the whole graph could help you find problems that exist in more than one level. A filter on the object being shown could help keeping it clean and readable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A profiler would allow you to see what objects are created at runtime. This is the output of JProfiler for instance:

[image: jprofiler heap walker]
<sub>(source: [ej-technologies.com](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/images/screenshots/heap_walker_references_fsb.png))</sub>

Comment: JProbe is another profiler that has a similar sort of memory profiling feature. I used it ~10 years ago to fix some Java code written by people who mistakenly thought it wasn't possible to have memory leaks in Java. To find leas you take a "snapshot" at a particular point, do a set of operations in your program that you think may be leaky and then return the program to it's original state. Any objects created after the snapshot pointed to by objects created before the snapshot are potential leaky objects.

Answer (score 2):

Sun have developed the [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net) which includes memory and process profiling. It also supports plugins for technology such as OSGi.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting use case would be memory analysis and optimization. This is precisely what [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) is about. Check it out.

[alt text http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/memoryanalyzer/files/2008/05/dom_tree.gif](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/memoryanalyzer/files/2008/05/dom_tree.gif)

Answer (score 1):

For **visualising graph structures** (including object graphs), there are lots of tools based on GraphViz: http://www.graphviz.org/

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Object Graph Visualizer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ogvisualizer/?source=navbar) which displays classes and objects in 3D. For now it lacks an API to automate the initialization, however it shouldn't be too difficult to add this functionality.
Source code also on [Github](https://github.com/Nurtak/ObjectGraphVisualization).

Edit: There is already work being done in that direction apparently:
https://eprints.hsr.ch/491/

[image: OGV]

Answer (score 0):

not sure if that  is what you are aiming at, but [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)  will do pretty much all of that.

it will take a heap of compiling  code  and turn it into cross referenced html, rtf of pdf.
completed will calling tree for each function and   "referenced by  "  for each variable

Comment: Sorry, I meant objects being used at runtime.